# Add custom meta after the order data in WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am looking to add custom meta after the order data in WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips. If a Custom Field is present on a WooCommerce order,

In my code my custom field name is `wholesale_order`.

For this I make use of:

```php
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data', 'add_due_date', 10, 2 );
function add_due_date() {

 $order_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wholesale_order', true );
  if( $order_data ) {
      // Do stuff
     }
}
```

---

Unfortunately without the desired result, I think the `$post->ID` is incorrect and probably the `get_post_meta`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try:

```
function action_wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data( $template_type, $order ) {
    // Get meta
    $wholesale_order = $order->get_meta( 'wholesale_order' );

    echo $wholesale_order;
}
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data', 'action_wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data', 10, 2 );
```

---

If that works you can expand your code to something like:

```
function action_wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data( $template_type, $order ) {
    // Get meta
    $wholesale_order = $order->get_meta( 'wholesale_order' );

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $wholesale_order ) ) {
        ?>
        <tr class="my-class>
            <th><?php __( 'My title', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td>
                <?php echo $wholesale_order; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data', 'action_wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data', 10, 2 );
```

---

Action hook:

- `wpo_wcpdf_after_order_data` has 2 arguments `$template_type` & `$order`.
- After the order data - note that this is inside a table, and you should output the data as an html table row/cells.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `global $post` before `$order_data` variable.

Comment: I tried also with `global $post` but doesn't work